# Browsers unable to load a specific site (CouchDB server) after a while

Tags: firefox, curl, couchdb, chromium, cloudant

I've built a web application that uses CouchDB as its database. The application works just fine, and DB writes are very fast.

After a while, application looses ability to connect the CouchDB server (cloudant.com in this example). Rather than debugging my own application's codes, I tried to connect to cloudant by other tools, like Chromium (it works) and `curl` (it works). If I restart firefox, all starts going well. If I use Chromium, it works well for a while, then it starts to bring same symptoms.

What would cause a browser not to load such a specific site (which has a simple REST api, nothing more)?

Comment: How long does it keep working for?  Do you see that things go wrong after a few minutes, a few hours, or a few days?  Also if you use Firebug or other developer tools, do you see any errors when the connection stops working?  Maybe a little bit more info may help us to make some suggestions on what could be happening here.

Comment: It seems it's all about concurrent request limit: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5498#issuecomment-234911536